# Serilog configuration via appsettings.json for Application Insights

Tags: configuration, azure-application-insights, serilog, appsettings

I am trying to use https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration to read app settings and setup serilog for app insights: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights.  The issue I am having is that I cannot set the last parameters for ApplicationInsightsEvents call, which is a function that takes LogEvent and returns ITelemetry.  How can this be set via appsettings.json?

Basically, I want to replace the followoing line:
log.WriteTo.ApplicationInsightsEvents(instrumentationKey, level, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, TelemetryConverter.ConvertLogEventsToEnerGovTelemetry);

with a line inside appsettings.json

Thanks.

Comment: If you can provide some demo code, that would be better for other's understanding the issue.

Comment: Edited to add more info.

Answer (score 6):

Add a sink configuration to appsettings.json

```
      {
        "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
        "Args": {
          "instrumentationKey": "<instrumentationKey>",
          "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights",
          "outputTemplate": "[{Component}|{MachineName}|{ThreadId}] {Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] <{SourceContext}> {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
```

And

```
"Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights"
```

to "Serilog:Using" array

Answer (score 0):

Answered on GitHub: https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration/issues/165.  Just need to write an assembly and embed the final code there.